# How to calculate an element's scale, and translate values to have a point stay where the cursor is?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

The goal is to zoom in/out a view by scrolling, but the "origin" is where the cursor is.

Imagine a line (not box to be easier to imagine, and calculate it), which has numbers in it. If you put the cursor to a number, if you scroll, it has always to be at the center of the window.

An example with my best try:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const { x } = e;

  const mouseX = document.getElementById('mouseX');
  mouseX.style.transform = `translateX(${x}px)`
  
  const mouseXIndicator = document.getElementById('x');
  mouseXIndicator.innerText = x;
})

let scale = 1;
let translateX = 0;

window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  const { deltaY, x } = e;
  
  const leftIndicator = document.getElementById('left');
  const widthIndicator = document.getElementById('width');
  const translateXIndicator = document.getElementById('translateX');
  
  const line = document.querySelector('.line');
  
  scale = scale - deltaY / 1000;

  const left = line.offsetLeft * scale;
  const width = line.offsetWidth * scale;
  translateX = -(x - left - (width / 2)) / scale;
  
  leftIndicator.innerText = left;
  widthIndicator.innerText = width;
  translateXIndicator.innerText = translateX;
  
  line.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px) scale(${scale})`;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.line {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  flex-direction: column
}

#mouseX {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class='indicators'>
  <div>
    mouseX: <span id='x'></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    left: <span id='left'></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    width: <span id='width'></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    translateX: <span id='translateX'></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='line'>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>

<span id='mouseX'></span>
```

If you try it, it's very far away from close, because it's jumping, and some progress by not zooming exactly to the center of the element, but not to the right spot either.

When starting to scroll to 4 for example, the element should stay at its place (not jumping), and by slowly zooming, you should see a huge 4 at your screen.

Obviously the first idea was to set `transform-origin`, which seems reasonable if scale is 1, translates are 0. It just pushes the element to unexpected positions on the second scroll.

Had some ideas, different approaches, some did work with one case, not with another, drawn coordinate systems, where the center was the initial transform origin, but none was working with:

- not getting the actual left from `getBoundingClientRect`. I believe that knowing the actual scale value, actual x offset, and the original width of the element by `offsetWidth` should be enough, if the right pattern is known
- creating a pattern which is very close to 0, when the scrolling is minimal for example with a touchpad

So the goal is to make the above possible with only knowing:

- original width
- original left position
- scale
- translateX
- mouse X position